# can we render image sitecore mvc view using itemID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc

In my MVC view i'm able to get Image ItemID now want to render it
   i'm doing this as:

```
   // Getting ImageItemID
   ID myImageItemId = new ID(image.Substring(image.IndexOf('{', 0), 38));
   // Getting ImageItem according myImageItemId 
   Item myImageItem = db.GetItem(myImageItemId);
   @Html.Raw(myImageItem)
   <img src="@myImageItem"/>
```

please someone can hep to what mistake i'm doing here

Comment: Why not just render the image URL into the `src` field using `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(myImageItem)`?

Comment: I agree with Jammykam. That to me seems like the easiest way to render the image unless you need it page editor enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a dedicated action that will return the contents of the actual image by it's id:

```
public ActionResult Image(int imageID)
{
    byte[] image = SomeService.GetImageBytes(imageID);

    return File(image, "image/jpeg");
}
```

After that you can use this action in your view:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Image", "SomeController", new {imageID = myImageItem})"/>
```

Comment: actually it's a partial view which is rendering on Ajax Call so it's doesn't any Model & controller it's just for getting result from sitecore & rendering them

Comment: You should create a separate action (you can create a separate controller for that too) which will return the image

Comment: you mean here i need to create separate controller for this

Comment: You need to do whatever suits your best, you can create a separate controller or you can use an existing controller and add this action there

Comment: what is your mean by "SomeService" in controller ActionResult method

Comment: It's a service that will return the image by it's id